# Can't get EditText to get focus and popup keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am not able to set the focus on the `EditText` box at the end. I have tried almost every trick on google! I am not able to get it to focus nor am I able to bring the keyboard.

I have also tried setting the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` but this also didn't solve the problem.

Please help

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spnIncidentCategory"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/iv_border"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView24" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/drop_down"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spnIncidentCategory"
        android:id="@+id/imgSpinner1"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/spnIncidentCategory" />


    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pbSendInfo"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:progressTint="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/txtPlaceHolder"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spnIncidentCategory" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please Select an Incident Category"
        android:id="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pbSendInfo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please Select an Incident Description"
        android:id="@+id/textView25"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPlaceHolder" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spnIncidentDescription"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/iv_border"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spnIncidentCategory"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView25" />

<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/txtPlaceHolder2"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spnIncidentDescription"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/drop_down"
    android:id="@+id/imgSpinner2"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spnIncidentDescription"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/spnIncidentDescription" />

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter any comment that will help resolve the issue faster"
        android:id="@+id/textView26"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPlaceHolder2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/txtPlaceHolder3"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtUserComments" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSendInfo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPlaceHolder3"
        android:src="@mipmap/send_info"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtUserComments"

        android:editable="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Enter Your Comments"
        android:textColorHint="#86acafb9"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:elevation="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_padding_material"
        android:inputType="textImeMultiLine|text|textMultiLine"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView26"
        android:elegantTextHeight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

This line in `EditText` is causing the problem. Remove it and it should work.

Comment: Yazici - I have no idea why that should be the problem, but it was. Now its working fine. Thanks a lot! Accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The soft keyboards in Android are highly unpredictable. There are several problems related to editText focus and showing the keyboard. Try these methods to show or hide keyboard programmatically in your app

```
public static void hideKeyboard(FragmentActivity activity) {
        // Check if no view has focus:
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }

    public static void showKeyboard(FragmentActivity activity) {
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @VipuKumar - I tried this and called from OnFocusChange. But its not getting called Here is my code  txtComments.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            #Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), hasFocus +"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                showKeyboard(getActivity());
                       }
        });

Comment: Have you programmatically called et.requestFocus()?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to give focus programmatically?

`text.requestFocus();`

Comment: Yes I have...as soon as I create it.